# how to compute expectation and variance of r.v.(geometric d.)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

how to compute expectation and variance of r.v.(geometric d.)
straight forward using definition and using MGF
 1/(1-z)^(2)

i have tried using the expectation of geometric d. E(x)=x*(N1 C x)(N2 C n-x) / (N C n) but i don't think this is the the equation I'm lost . I know for the MGF E(x) you take the derivative and set t=0 but what to i plug into the equation? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your moment generating function is incorrect. So your mistake is one you made earlier

The MGF of a geometric distribution is
$$f(z)=\mathbb E(e^{zX}) = \frac{1-p}{1-pe^t}.$$

So for the mean and variance you can calculate $\mathbb E(X) = f'(0)$ and $\mathbb E(X^2) = f''(0)$. I'm assuming this either is homework or an exercise in a book you're reading so I'll let you finish it off yourself.